# How to remove a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6

At some point in my application workflow, I have one showing `UIViewController`. And as I press the Home button, I leave the application, leaving it running in the background.

However, when I return to the app, I would like the showing `UIViewController` not to appear again. I would like it to be removed or destroyed or anything like that.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add observer to UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification in your `viewcontroller` class. Try this in the `init` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

then in the enterBackground method, you can pop or dismiss your `viewcontroller`.

remember call this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

in the `dealloc`

Answer (score 1):

There is a notification you can register to receive that's called `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` (also `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`).  If you listen for that in your view controller, you can arrange for it to be popped or dismissed depending on how it came to be displayed in the first place.